# Can anyone name a WiMax USB dongle that works with 10.04?

Tags: wireless, usb, 10.04

I need to find a WiMax USB dongle that works on Ubuntu (driver support).

I googled for it but could not come up with any up to date information.

I wonder if anyone can tell from experience that Model-XYZ works smoothly, or tell how one was able to get ModelXYZ to work under ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get ZTE AX225 WiMax USB Modem to work in both ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10
I used the Sprint4GDeveloperPackage, I added the AX225 modem's vendor and product IDs to the source code and compiled.
I used the usb_modeswich with a eject command to switch the usb device from mass storage to wimax modem.

Compiled the CM from the package (needed OpenSSL source, was not included) and used the
wimaxd deamon and wimaxc client to connect using a conf file wimaxd.conf which I got its data from my CM on windows machine.